# Verifying a result of the exponential of a matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

I used an algorithm issued from Cayley's and Hamilton's theorem to compute the exponential of the following matrix:

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

More precisely, I want $e^{tA}$ and I found:

$e^{tA} = e^{-t}(\dfrac{(I-A)^2}{4})+e^t\dfrac{I+A}{2}+t(A-I)(\dfrac{I+A}{2})+e^t\dfrac{(I+A)(I-A)}{4}$

Is there any way to verify that result?

Comment: Do you know how to decompose $A$ into semisimple and nilpotent parts?

Comment: I've never heard of using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for matrix exponentiation.  Could you clarify what the steps of the algorithm are supposed to be?

Comment: There is an unmatched open parenthesis in your expression for $e^{tA}$.

Comment: In using Cayley-Hamilton, I presume you're appealing to the fact that $e^{tA}$ should be expressible in terms of $1,A,A^2$? (That $A^3$ can be expressed in these terms follows from Cayley-Hamilton since the characteristic polynomial is cubic.)

Comment: Using Mathematica to check the computation, it looks like it should be $t e^t$ instead of $t$ alone in front of the third term in your expression for $e^{tA}$.

Comment: I think the OP mean something like this: [Computing the Matrix Exponential: The Cayley-Hamilton Method](http://web.mit.edu/2.151/www/Handouts/CayleyHamilton.pdf)